# Episerver specialized property validation

Tags: episerver

I have a Form Grid Block that has a specialized property as given below

[Display(Name = "Form Access Group", Description = "Form Access Group", GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content, Order = 400)]

```
    [EditorDescriptor(EditorDescriptorType = typeof(CollectionEditorDescriptor<FormActionsAccess>))]



    public virtual IList<FormActionsAccess> OptimizelyFormActionsAccess { get; set; }
```

Specialized property class

public class FormActionsAccess

```
{

    [Display(Name = "Okta groups", Description = "Okta Groups", Order = 100)]

    [SelectOne(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(OktaGroupSelectionFactory))]

    public virtual string OktaGroup { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Form Operation Access", Description = "Form Operation Access", Order = 200)]

    [SelectMany(SelectionFactoryType = typeof(FormSubmissionDataActionSelectionFactory))]

    [RestrictDeleteOption(nameof(OktaGroup), "Everyone")]

    public virtual string FormOperationAccess { get; set; }

}
```

Here’s the output for the same:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYaL0.jpg)
I am looking for validation to restrict when oktagroup Everyone is selected with form operation access delete.

Answer (score 0):

If your block type is called `FormGridBlock`, I would simply add a class implementing `IValidate<FormGridBlock>` to check if `OktaGroup` is `Everyone` while `FormOperationAccess` is `"delete"` and if so yield a validation error.